# parent.children.length vs declaring a variable

Tags: javascript, performance, processing-efficiency

I have a parent element with n number of children in it. I created a `while loop` checking if `parent.children.length !== x`. I will then add a child till it's equal.

Which is more efficient / faster:

- Add `parent.children.length` to a var, then in the while loop increment it by 1. Like this:

  ```
  var childrenLength = parent.children.length;
  while (childrenLength !== someNumber) {
      parent.appendChild(someArray[childrenLength]);
      childrenLength++;
  }

  // Or can increment childrenLength when accessing it
  while (childrenLength !== someNumber) {
      parent.appendChild(someArray[childrenLength++]);
  }
  ```
- Use `parent.children.length`. Like this:

  ```
  while (parent.children.length !== someNumber) {
      parent.appendChild(someArray[parent.children.length]);
  }
  ```

Comment: Why did you increase `childrenLength`, but not `parent.children.length`?

Comment: what have your tests determined regarding speed of each?

Comment: @RaxWeber `parent.children.length` automatically gets increased when I add a child to it.

Comment: @charlietfl I haven't. That's why I'm asking, lol. I don't know how to test it. I also want to know which is more efficient.

Comment: there are perf test sites you can try... or use google to figure out how to set up a performance test yourself using your browser dev tools

Comment: I'd probably write it the clearest way, i.e., the last way, and wouldn't worry about it further unless I noticed a performance problem when it runs. If you are going to do it the first way, I think a `for` loop would be clearer than a `while` loop. (Also, I'd use `<` rather than `!==`, because I'd be worried about the endless loop that would occur if there were already more than `someNumber` children.)

Comment: My bet is that the performance of your example will not matter. Maximise your codes readability, and don't prematurely optimise. If you are noticing performance issues it will be somewhere else in your application.

Comment: @nnnnnn In my actual project, I have an if statement checking if > or <. If it's less, then I add children with loop, if more, then I remove children with loop. (Let me know if you understand that.) Now that I changed the while loop to > and <. I can take away the if statement, correct? Will anything change performance wise?